# Fragment not getting inflated with RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I created a `RecyclerView` which should be displayed in my fragment.

The recyclerView gets filled with Data from a database i created with room and i also provides some dummy data so its not empty from the start.

But when i open the app the fragment is just empty. I also tried to add a textview just to see if my fragment gets inflated but the recycler is empty, but even the `TextView` wasn't displayed.

Here is the Fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
 class HistoryFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_history) {

private val viewModel: PurchaseViewmodel by viewModels()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val binding = FragmentHistoryBinding.bind(view)

    val exampleAdapter = ExampleAdapter()

    binding.apply{
        recyclerView.apply{

            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            adapter = exampleAdapter
            setHasFixedSize(true)
        }
    }
    viewModel.receipts.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ 
        exampleAdapter.submitList(it)
    }
}
}
```

And the Adapter:

```
class ExampleAdapter : ListAdapter<Receipts,ExampleAdapter.ReceiptsViewHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ReceiptsViewHolder {
    val binding = ReceiptsBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
    return ReceiptsViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ReceiptsViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(currentItem)
}

class ReceiptsViewHolder(private val binding: ReceiptsBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){ 
    fun bind (receipts: Receipts) {
        binding.apply {
            storeHistory.text = receipts.store
            amountHistory.text = receipts.total
            dateHistory.text  = receipts.date
        }
    }
}
class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Receipts>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Receipts, newItem: Receipts) =
        oldItem.id == newItem.id


    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Receipts, newItem: Receipts) =
        oldItem == newItem
}
```

}

Comment: Have you `override getItemCount()`?

Comment: No I dont have that implementet. How would i do that?

Comment: Sorry I though you extends from `RecyclerView.Adapter` but it's not needed in `ListAdapter`

Comment: Ah damn alright.

Comment: I had a chance to look at the provided sample, and the issues seems to be in the layout.. please have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely arises because you haven’t overridden the `onCreateView()` for the fragment.

You should override it and return the binding root from it:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = FragmentHistoryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
}
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't chane even with the onCreateView()

Comment: Strange then I’d suspect your fragment is not attaching could you share the minimum working example on GitHub perhaps?

Comment: https://github.com/UniDueJonasQuurck/NLP_Expense_tracker Here is the link to the project, I don't have the minimal working project avaiable I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the History fragment layout, you need to change the height of the `RecyclerView` from `wrap_content` to `match_parent`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.History.HistoryFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:padding="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]